# Can a sink be the next data source in Apache Flink

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm using Apache Flink to process streaming data.

Saying that I have two jar files `a.jar` and `b.jar`. My question is if it is possible to use the sink of `a.jar` as the data source of `b.jar`.

If it's possible, can you show me a simple example?

If not, what could I do? Must I use something like a Database to store the output of the sink of `a.jar` and use the Database as the data source of `b.jar`?

Comment: Could you elaborate more details about your scenario? Like why you want to split the logic into two different jobs instead a single one.

Comment: @JiayiLiao  Well, in my case, `a.jar` and `b.jar` are independent and heavy, and two developers are working together. So I'm thinking if the two developers can work independently and concurrently, it would be great.

Comment: Why don't simply use Kafka?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get exactly-once guarantees, you'll have to implement this decoupling with a stream storage layer that supports transactions and stream replay.